# How to distinguish between "Addon is not installed" and "Addon is not enabled"?

Tags: python, add-on

I want to check if an addon exists and if it is enabled. So i tried:

```
loaded_default, loaded_state = addon_utils.check(addon_name)
```

But i found that i can not distinguish between the 2 cases:

- Addon is not installed
- Addon is not enabled

So in the case where i want to programmatically enable an addon, i can only do:

```
addon_name="myaddon"
default, state = addon_utils.check(addon_name)
print ("%s: default:%s, state:%s" % (addon_name, default, state) )
if default == False and state is None:
    print("%s is not installed or not enabled by default" % addon_name)

if state != True :
    print("Try to enable module %s On The Fly ..." % addon_name )
    try:
        mod = addon_utils.enable(addon_name, default_set=False, persistent=True)
        if mod:
            state = True
    except:
        print("Could not enable %s on the fly. Ignore" % addon_name )
```

But this is ugly. Especially when the module does not exist then i get a stack trace in the console, even when i use a try/except block. For the the example above i get this in the console:

```
myaddon: default:False, state:None
myaddon is not installed or not enabled by default
Try to enable module myaddon On The Fly ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\blendergit\cmake-build\bin\Release\2.71\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 299, in enable
    mod = __import__(module_name)
ImportError: No module named 'myaddon'
```

Is it possible to make this more elegant and avoid to see the stack trace when the child addon does not exist ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the addon is not 'installed' (i.e. unknown from Blender side), then it won’t be listed in `addon_utils.addons_fake_modules`. So the solution is:

```
mod = None
addon_name = "myaddon"
if addon_name not in addon_utils.addons_fake_modules:
    print("%s: Addon not installed." % addon_name)
else:
    default, state = addon_utils.check(addon_name)
    if not state:
        try:
            mod = addon_utils.enable(addon_name, default_set=False, persistent=False)
        except:
            print("%s: Could not enable Addon on the fly." % addon_name )

if mod:
    print("%s: enabled and running." % addon_name)
```

Comment: Yes, that was the missing link :)

Comment: You should replace `if state != True` by `if not state`